# PHP Recursive Loop using UASORT on Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I am writing a script that loops through a multidimensional array and it's working as hoped (sort of) but I get errors that I just can't remedy.

I am still not that comfortable building loops to manage nested arrays.

Here is my code. The goal is to sort each layer by the value of the **sequence** key and in the end I export the array as json.

The sequence key may or may not exist in every sub array so that may need some sort of **if clause**

```php
<?php
$list = [
        "key" => "book",
        "sequence" => 1,
        "items" => [
            [
                "key" => "verse",
                "sequence" => 2,
                "items" => [
                    ["sequence" => 3],
                    ["sequence" => 1],
                    ["sequence" => 2],
                ],
            ],
            [
                "key" => "page",
                "sequence" => 1,
                "items" => [
                    [
                        "key" => "page",
                        "sequence" => 2,
                        "items" => [
                            ["sequence" => 2],
                            ["sequence" => 1],
                            ["sequence" => 3],
                        ],
                    ],
                    [
                        "key" => "paragraph",
                        "sequence" => 1,
                        "items" => [
                            ["sequence" => 2],
                            ["sequence" => 1],
                            ["sequence" => 3],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];

function sortit(&$array){

    foreach($array as $key => &$value){
        //If $value is an array.
        if(is_array($value)){

            if($key == "items"){
                uasort($value, function($a,&$b) {
                   return $a["sequence"] <=> $b["sequence"];
                });

            }
            //We need to loop through it.
            sortit($value);
        } else{
            //It is not an array, so print it out.
            echo $key . " : " . $value . "<br/>";
        }
    }
}


sortit($list);

echo "<pre>";

print_r($list);

?>
```

Here is the output and error I am getting, and I think I understand why the error is being thrown but at the same time I can not implement the proper checks needed to fix the error.

```
key : book
sequence : 1
key : page
sequence : 1

E_WARNING : type 2 -- Illegal string offset 'sequence' -- at line 39

E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: sequence -- at line 39
sequence : 1
sequence : 2
sequence : 3
sequence : 1
key : page

E_WARNING : type 2 -- Illegal string offset 'sequence' -- at line 39

E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined index: sequence -- at line 39
sequence : 1
sequence : 2
sequence : 3
sequence : 2
key : verse
```

Not that I am worried to much but another thing that I would like is the array to still be structured in the original order, ie: `key, sequence, items`

Comment: Your data is a little bit confusing: `key => page` has an `items` array that is not 2d and doesn't match the format elsewhere in the array. Is this the only irregularity in the data (other than the mentioned missing `sequence` keys? BTW, how should arrays with missing `sequence` keys be sorted? Can you show expected output?

Comment: @ggorlen Good looks on the pages data, that was an oversight as the actual array is more in depth so I created this array as a test. I am updating that now.

As far as the missing sequence, that won't normally be the case but it's possible to have other arrays of data that do not need a sequence and should not be sorted.

Comment: Ah, I see, so if they do have an `items` key, we can be guaranteed that all elements in `items` are arrays that have a `sequence` key?

Comment: Yes, that is correct @ggorlen

Comment: @ggorlen I would have thought that adding the clause `if($key == "items")` to make sure we were dealing with the current array which contains the `sequence` key. But for some reason it is still throwing an error.

I think my lack of understanding of recursive loops is what is messing me up.

Comment: You have the right idea, but the outer level is probably confusing you, because it doesn't match the structure of the inner levels. You'd need to wrap it in `[]` to make it behave like the inner arrays so that your recursive function works. Basically, the top layer isn't recursively similar to any of its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `usort` and array references makes it straightforward. If we're dealing with an array with a set `item` key, sort the `item` array and recurse on its children, otherwise, we're at a leaf node and can return.

```
function seqSort(&$arr) {
    if (is_array($arr) && array_key_exists("items", $arr)) {
        usort($arr["items"], function ($a, $b) {
            return $a["sequence"] - $b["sequence"];
        });

        foreach ($arr["items"] as &$item) {
            $item = seqSort($item);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}
```

Result:

```
array (
  'key' => 'book',
  'sequence' => 1,
  'items' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'key' => 'page',
      'sequence' => 1,
      'items' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'key' => 'page',
          'sequence' => 1,
          'items' => 
          array (
            0 => 
            array (
              'sequence' => 1,
            ),
            1 => 
            array (
              'sequence' => 2,
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'sequence' => 3,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
      'key' => 'verse',
      'sequence' => 2,
      'items' => 
      array (
        0 => 
        array (
          'sequence' => 1,
        ),
        1 => 
        array (
          'sequence' => 2,
        ),
        2 => 
        array (
          'sequence' => 3,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

[Try it!](https://repl.it/repls/DistinctSpanishCoderesource)

Note that the outermost structure is a root node that isn't part of an array and can't be sorted (this may be unintentional and causing confusion).

Comment: Yeah, the outermost level will never have more than one entry. This is a great function, thank you. I am going to study it in hopes I can figure out what you did.